# How to get XY values of a HitTest on a series chart in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am charting particle motion on a Chart in VB, and wanted to be able to show the X and Y value of a point on the series when clicked by the mouse. I looked online and found that using Chart.HitTest method can give you the index of a point, but couldn't find a way to get the coordinates from that point.
Is there even a way to get the coordinates?

I tried converting the result of the HitTest into a DataPoint object, but it doesnt seem to be available in the Version of VB Im using.(School computers still use express 2012)

my code so far:

```
Private Sub Chart1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseDown
    Dim result = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

End Sub
```

Comment: Been a while for me, from memory it's something like the key is HitTestResult.PointIndex.  Then use that value to look up your data point in DataPointCollection

Comment: Hii sorry for late reply, but yeah I looked up DataPointCollection and just like DataPoint object, its not in vb 2012 :(. I had to use another method that is somewhat working, but thank you very much for the suggestion. Have a good day!